# Too much space after sections when I change parskip

Tags: spacing, sectioning, parskip

I changed the `parident` and `parskip` of my document. But now there is a huge empty space after the sections. How can I reduce the space after a section?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
Test test test test.

Test test test test.

\subsection{Test}
Test test test test.

Test test test test.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should probably use the [`parskip`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package rather than changing those values yourself. As for the spacing, you can use `\titlespacing` from the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to change the spacing. For example

```
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{-6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
```

seems more or less reasonable for the spacing around the `\section`. Something similar would be needed for for `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`.

Comment: I can just add that, as mentioned in the `parskip` manual, the KOMA classes (and `memoir`, for that matter) have the features of that package builtin. Add e.g. `parskip=full` as an option to the documentclass. There are more choices, see the KOMA-script manual.

Comment: @Torbjorn: Ah okay. Then in that case it's best to use the provided methods. I never use KOMA or memoir so I'm (more than) a little ignorant of them.